# Json.net serializer is handling `PreserveReferencesHandling` and `ReferenceLoopHandling` wrong

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

consider the following model

```
public class Root
{
    public static int latestID = 0;
    public Root()
    {
        SpecificBranchA = new A(this) { BranchID = latestID + 1 };
    }
    public A SpecificBranchA { get; }
}
public class A
{
    public Root Owner { get; }
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public A(Root owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }
    public List<B> Children { get; } = new List<B>();
}
public class B
{
    public A Owner { get; }
    public int LeafID { get; set; }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public B(A owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }
}
```

and this example instance :

```
var root = new Root();
root.Obj.Children.Add(new B(root.Obj) { LeafID = 1 });
root.Obj.Children.Add(new B(root.Obj) { LeafID = 2 });
root.Obj.Children.Add(new B(root.Obj) { LeafID = 3 });
```

this gives a wrong json when serializing with these settings :

```
var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{                   
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,

    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, //only for reading simplicity
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented //only for reading simplicity
});
```

result :

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "$type": "TestJSONSerializer.Root, TestJSONSerializer",
  "SpecificBranchA": {
    "$type": "TestJSONSerializer.A, TestJSONSerializer",
    "Owner": {
      "$ref": "1"
    },
    "BranchID": 1,
    "Children": [
      {
        "$id": "2",
        "$type": "TestJSONSerializer.B, TestJSONSerializer",
        "Owner": {
          "$id": "3",
          "$type": "TestJSONSerializer.A, TestJSONSerializer",
          "Owner": {
            "$ref": "1"
          },
          "BranchID": 1,
          "Children": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            },
            {
              "$id": "4",
              "$type": "TestJSONSerializer.B, TestJSONSerializer",
              "Owner": {
                "$ref": "3"
              },
              "LeafID": 2
            },
            {
              "$id": "5",
              "$type": "TestJSONSerializer.B, TestJSONSerializer",
              "Owner": {
                "$ref": "3"
              },
              "LeafID": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "LeafID": 1
      },
      {
        "$ref": "4"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here you can note that the object created in `A`'s constructor stored in the property `A.SpecificBranchA` gets serialized twice, and you get some weird nesting behavior.

but you don't get that behavior when serializing the `A` object separately.

(yes this behavior doesn't occur when you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root.SpecificBranchA,...)`)

it looks like a bug in Json.net , but i am not sure if i am doing something wrong

Comment: i also posted an issue on Json.net repo https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1841

Comment: Possibly related: [Issue with serializing/deserializing object graph with self-referencing objects in combination with JSON constructor. #715](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/715), [PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects deserialize does not work with non-default constructor #678](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/678), [References are not preserved during serialization of collection if the property is read-only #1329](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1841).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it appears i was doing things the wrong way not according to Json.net design (thanks to @dbc's comment)

i changed the model slightly and everything worked

in the root class, i changed the definition of property `SpecificBranchA` to the following

```
[JsonProperty]
public A SpecificBranchA { get; private set; }
```

and the serialization works as expected.
so i think any property that contains an object with reference loop, must have a setter (even if private) and be marked with `[JsonProperty]`. if either is missing, the serialization gets the wrong behavior.

---

related issues posted by @dbc

- [Issue with serializing/deserializing object graph with self-referencing objects in combination with JSON constructor. #715](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/715)
- [References are not preserved during serialization of collection if the property is read-only #1329](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1329)
- [PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects deserialize does not work with non-default constructor #678](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/678)